# protecting alarm and sleep with some kind of mutex or semaphore mechanism

Tags: c, linux

Since alarm and sleep both are using SIGALRM so there may be a conflict.
Can any one suggest me to protect alarm and sleep with some kind of mutex or semaphore mechanism apart from creating any new timers with setitimer or timer_create etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't use them. Actually the text in POSIX that allows `sleep` to use `SIGALRM` is conflicting with the requirement that `sleep` be thread-safe, and has been fixed for the next version of POSIX, but it would still be best to avoid it.

In place of `sleep`, use `nanosleep` or `clock_nanosleep`.

In place of `alarm`, depending on what you want to do, you could use POSIX timers or some other mechanism. The whole idiom of `alarm` to interrupt a stuck operation with a signal after a timeout does not work for multi-threaded programs, though, and so really you should just drop the whole `alarm` idiom and use a different approach for modern code.